# how to get parent div from element inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the dynamic input id custom_field_42, and i need to get the form-group div to change display to block from none, how can i do that?

```
<div class="form-group row g-mb-5" style="display:none;">
  <label for="custom_field_42" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label g-mb-10 text-right">insteructyor</label>
  
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control u-form-control rounded-0 custom_field_input" id="custom_field_42" name="insteructyor" placeholder="insteructyor">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this, it doesn't work.

```
$('#custom_field_42').closest('.form-group').show()
```

---

**Community edit...**

Actually, this works:

```js
$('#custom_field_42').closest('.form-group').show();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group row g-mb-5" style="display:none;">
  <label for="custom_field_42" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label g-mb-10 text-right">insteructyor</label>

  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control u-form-control rounded-0 custom_field_input" id="custom_field_42" name="insteructyor" placeholder="insteructyor">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine. See the snippet above.

Comment: @isherwood yeah i tried again, its working fine with my original code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Element.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the first parent element which matches a selector, which, in our case, is `.row`:

```js
const input = custom_field_42;
input.closest('.row').style.display="block";
```

```html
<div class="form-group row g-mb-5" style="display:none;">

  <label for="custom_field_42" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label g-mb-10 text-right">insteructyor</label>

  <div class="col-sm-10">

    <input type="text" class="form-control u-form-control rounded-0 custom_field_input" id="custom_field_42" name="insteructyor" placeholder="insteructyor">

  </div>
</div>
```